# Where was this picture taken in 1932?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, photography

This picture was taken about 1932 in central Europe -  probably in Czechoslovakia, maybe in Budweis.[image]

Answer (score 61):

This is the [Schloss Charlottenburg (Charlottenburg Palace)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schloss_Charlottenburg), a [Baroque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baroque) palace in [Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin).

[image]

(Image: Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license; Author: ernstol)

Comment: That was quick.  Thank you!!  I'll post another mystery photo.

Answer (score 22):

As comparison with the original photo of the question:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tagesspiegel.de](https://m.tagesspiegel.de/images/bundesarchiv_schloss_charlottenburg/13695036/4-format3040.jpg))</sub>

- Schloß Charlottenburg (Berlin) after the bombing during the night of the 22/23rd of November 1943

The dark colors of the building was caused by coal dust, since in that area coal was the main form of heating until the late 1970's.

---

**Sources**:

- [Berlin-Charlottenburg: So wurde Schloss Charlottenburg gerade noch gerettet - Bezirke - Berlin - Tagesspiegel](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/bezirke/so-wurde-schloss-charlottenburg-gerade-noch-gerettet-6619534.html)